# Struct Variable Query

Tags: c++, class, c++11, struct

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef struct trie
{
    int arr[26];
    bool isleaf;
    trie(int isleaf)
    {
        this->isleaf=9;
        cout<<isleaf<<endl;
        isleaf=false;
        cout<<isleaf<<endl;
        cout<<this->isleaf<<endl;
    }
}* tr;
//void inser(s)
int main()
{
   tr k=new trie(3);
   cout<<k->isleaf;
}
```

Works Fine and outputs

```
3
0
1
1
```

But in

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef struct trie
{
    int arr[26];
    bool isleaf;
    trie(int isleaf)
    {
        cout<<isleaf<<endl;
        isleaf=false;
        cout<<isleaf<<endl;
        cout<<this->isleaf<<endl;
    }
}* tr;
//void inser(s)
int main()
{
   tr k=new trie(3);
   cout<<k->isleaf;
}
```

I get

```
3
0
68
68
```

I understand that it is uninitialized but still why 68?

If use a normal bool either in global or inside function and print it without initializing i get 0,then why not here?

And can somebody also point out some good source to clear doubts about such variable declarations , public and private concepts , and OOPS, difference between structs and classes etc.

Comment: Asking for the behavior of undefined behavior is mostly futile.

Comment: the thing is i am not asking about what value gets assigned to it.
why a bool gives a 68 when it is supposed to be if 1 bit

Comment: Because that's what was there when the program loaded? Because the compiler you use always initializes ints to 68? Because that's your lucky number?

Comment: In case  of global variables they are automatically initialized with default values.

Comment: @RohanAggarwal _"when it is supposed to be if 1 bit"_ There's no such thing like a _single bit variable_.

Comment: no no i know that we work in bytes.
but shouldn't the cout print according considering bool can be only 0 or 1

Comment: like if you do 
    bool a=5; 
    cout<<a;
it will print 1

Comment: bool is not stored on one bit

Comment: the true lie is that bool is just an integer ^^.

Comment: ya then why do we get 68 here
we should get either 0 or 1

Comment: because the value stored there before in the memory wasn't interpreted as bool expression

Comment: ok @W.F. that seems logical
so until i initialize it , it will never be treated as a bool

Comment: @RohanAggarwal Also read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) please.

Comment: Try this code on other OS/compilers. You will find many will output 0. It's very dependent on where/how you compile and run.

Comment: @gaurangvyas no i was not confused in that , just because when it was not initialized i wanted it to still give 0 or 1 , i was surprised on 68
now it got cleared

Comment: Don't typedef struct in C++.

Answer (score 0):

> **[basic.fundamental]/6** Values of type `bool` are either `true` or `false`.<sup>49</sup>
>
> Footnote 49) Using a `bool` value in ways described by this International Standard as “undefined,” such as by examining the value of an uninitialized automatic object, might cause it to behave as if it is neither `true` nor `false`.

Undefined behavior is undefined. That's the long and the short of it. It's really pointless to discuss why a program exhibiting undefined behavior happens to manifest it in a particular way.